Preview content by content type
Is it possible to Preview Drupal content by content type? Currently the preview template options are
page--node--preview--f7fd5df8-d58d-42f8-b274-8d224eddbb5a--full.html.twig
   ▪️ page--node--preview--f7fd5df8-d58d-42f8-b274-8d224eddbb5a.html.twig
   ✅ page--node--preview.html.twig
   ▪️ page--node.html.twig
   ▪️ page.html.twig

...but is there a preprocess function or solution to allow preview by Content Type e.g. page--node--preview--CONTENT-TYPE.html.twig
I tried below with no luck from another forum:
function THEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $routeMatch = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $node_preview = $routeMatch->getParameter('node_preview');
  if ($node_preview instanceof NodeInterface) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__node__preview__' . $node_preview->bundle();
    if ($view_mode_id = $routeMatch->getParameter('view_mode_id')) {
      $suggestions[] = 'page__node__preview__' . $node_preview->bundle() . '__' . $view_mode_id;
    }
  }
}


Don't think so that if there is any suggestion for node preview on the basis of content type exist.
I think the approach is correct. Can you please enter a route check to see if it generates the preview suggestion. Like the following
function yourtheme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
      
      if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() === 'entity.node.preview') {
        $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_preview'); 
        $suggestions[] = 'page__node__preview__' . $node->getType();
      }
 }

